# Calc - How to combine rows from multiple sheets into 1 main sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have several statements separating my various bank accounts in Calc, they all use the same columns and have a Date column which I sort them by.

I want to create a 'Overview' sheet which contains the rows of all my different sheets and then sort it all by Date so I can see an overview of my finances. How would I go about doing this without having to copy and paste every time I edit my individual sheets?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your initial design is not efficient. You should have only 1 worksheet, and add extra column for each information type. For example, suppose you have now an additional worksheet per account. You should add a column named "account", and write the account ID into it. You can filter by account, sort by it, add subtitles, etc.

Comment: hmm that is one way to do it, but i am dealing with a lot of rows and prefer to keep the source data in seperate sheets and each sheet has some other columns which are not the same as the others but i just wish to combine certain similar columns into 1 sheet.

Comment: Google Docs has a QUERY or EXPAND function, nothing in Calc?

Comment: then your other options are probably pivot table or macros. i don't any other automated option.

Comment: how do i do it using a pivot table exactly though? is there an example related to this. I'm thinking maybe i should just move it to Google Docs and do it from there